# Captcha verification using laravel

Tags: laravel

Hello I am creating and refreshing captcha and also validating captcha. I am valiating capcha as follows but i want to check captcha is valid or not juisng javascrit that with out refreshing ordersummary page. In my coding page is refresh.

```
<div style="display:none;" class="captcha mt-2">

        <form method="post" action="/order-confirm">
        <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
                    <div class="form-group refereshrecapcha">
                         {!! captcha_img('flat') !!}
                    </div>
                      <input id="captcha" class="" type="text" name="captcha" data-validation="required" >
                      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="refreshCaptcha()" style="margin-left: 5px;">Refresh</a>
                      @if ($errors->has('CaptchaCode'))
                                  <span class="help-block">
                                     <strong>{{ $errors->first('CaptchaCode') }}</strong>
                                  </span>
                                @endif
                               <button class="btn btn-sm continue confirm_cashon_delivery"  style="margin-left: 5px;">CONFIRM ORDER</button>
                         </form>
       </div>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshCaptcha(){
$.ajax({
url: "/refereshcapcha",
type: 'get',
  dataType: 'html',        
  success: function(json) {
    $('.refereshrecapcha').html(json);
  },
  error: function(data) {
    alert('Try Again.');
  }
});
}
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public function order_confirm(Request $req)
    {

        $this->validate($req, [
            'captcha' => 'required|captcha'
        ]);

      return view('ordersummary');
}
```

Comment: you can create ajax call to verify your captcha

Comment: @KamleshPaul plz edit my code because i use ajax but it can not validate captcha  so that i am using this method

Comment: only for captcha make on ajax call and appned one input in from then when form submit validate that input this is my solution may be somone can give you better solution

Comment: @KamleshPaul can you edit my code?